# C# - Replace two different parts of string at once

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a string which i want to change to a newer version by replacing some parts of it which are different.
Let's say i have this string:

```
My=name,My=surname
```

And i want to return:

```
name.surname
```

So i want to replace both My with `""` and `,` with `.`. Is it possible?

Comment: is this vb or c#??

Comment: There is any possibility that name or surname contain the substring "My" ?

Comment: VB and C# are different languages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str = str.Replace("My=", "").Replace(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can guarantee that neither name or surname contains the string "My" then, the answer from Tim is the right one. However if "name" or  "surname" contain the string "My" things are more complex

```
string input = "My=Steve,My=Myland";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string[] parts = input.Split(',');
foreach (string p in parts)
{
    string[] subs = p.Split('=');
    sb.Append(subs[1] + ".");
}
if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Tim replaces `"My="` not just My, there are little chance someone has that in his name or surname

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yes I agree with you, I wrote this answer just to show an alternative way and after the first draft of Tim answer.  Now the chances of a My= in a surname are pretty inexistant but anyway...

Comment: Maybe simply using Regex.Replace would remove some of the boilerplate (it uses a StringBuilder internally) ?

Comment: Well, I think that a Regex is overkill for this but yes you could try to show another alternative with Regex. Mine is costly in performances (albeit the real impact depends on many factors) Still Tim's answer is the better one given the context.

Comment: I was about to show it ; but thought it would be overkill too (without further context at least), not sure it's worth an answer when the "good" one is already there